# Magento query doesn't filter on category_id

Tags: magento-1.9, category, attributes

On my live site I'm trying to get all products in a specific category. This works on a test environment with exactly the same code, but not on the live site. This is the code:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    // Select which fields to load into the product
    // * will load all fields but it is possible to pass an array of
    // select fields to load
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    $subCategories = explode(',', $currentCategory->getAllChildren());

    $products->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left');
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => array('finset' => $subCategories)));
    $products->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');

    $products->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
    $products->getSelect()->limit(8);
```

When I echo `$products->getSelect()`this is the query I see:

```
SELECT `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`cost`, `e`.`created_at`, `e`.`exclude_from_supply_needs`, `e`.`gift_message_available`, `e`.`has_options`, `e`.`image_label`, `e`.`is_recurring`, `e`.`links_exist`, `e`.`links_purchased_separately`, `e`.`links_title`, `e`.`name`, `e`.`news_from_date`, `e`.`news_to_date`, `e`.`price`, `e`.`price_type`, `e`.`price_view`, `e`.`recurring_profile`, `e`.`required_options`, `e`.`shipment_type`, `e`.`short_description`, `e`.`sku`, `e`.`sku_type`, `e`.`small_image`, `e`.`small_image_label`, `e`.`special_from_date`, `e`.`special_price`, `e`.`special_to_date`, `e`.`tax_class_id`, `e`.`thumbnail`, `e`.`thumbnail_label`, `e`.`updated_at`, `e`.`url_key`, `e`.`url_path`, `e`.`visibility`, `e`.`weight`, `e`.`weight_type`, `e`.`color`, `e`.`color_value`, `e`.`custom_design_from`, `e`.`custom_design_to`, `e`.`custom_layout_update`, `e`.`description`, `e`.`gallery`, `e`.`image`, `e`.`lengte`, `e`.`lengte_value`, `e`.`manufacturer`, `e`.`manufacturer_value`, `e`.`media_gallery`, `e`.`meta_description`, `e`.`meta_keyword`, `e`.`meta_title`, `e`.`minimal_price`, `e`.`msrp`, `e`.`msrp_display_actual_price_type`, `e`.`msrp_enabled`, `e`.`old_id`, `e`.`samples_title`, `e`.`grootte`, `e`.`grootte_value`, `e`.`product_status`, `e`.`status`, `e`.`uitgelicht_categorie`, `e`.`uitgelicht_categorie_value`, `e`.`uitgelicht_homepagina`, `e`.`uitgelicht_homepagina_value`, `at_category_id`.`category_id` FROM `n5no_catalog_product_flat_2` AS `e` LEFT JOIN `n5no_catalog_category_product` AS `at_category_id` ON (at_category_id.`product_id`=e.entity_id) WHERE (e.status = 1) GROUP BY `e`.`entity_id` ORDER BY RAND() ASC LIMIT 8
```

On my test environment the query also contains a filter on the sub categories. The variable `$subCategories` is filled, so that's not the problem. I also tried doing it with static category id's and tried to change the whole query various ways. Everything works except the sorting on `category_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that the reason why this wasn't working was because I had flat mode turned on in `configuration` -> `catalog`. A simple solution apparently!